# Excel, how to find a value between two columns on one row?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a number of rows.

Each row has two values `start` and `end`, which can be located at different columns on each row.

`Start` always appears before `End`.

How can I use Excel to output the columns between start and end.

Comment: Can you add some example of data and desired output?

Comment: To rephrase: you need to locate "Start" and "End" in each row, and determine if the column number of "Start" is at least 2 less than that of "End"?

Comment: @Hynek Bernard I will try.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I am aware that this would be easier if Start and End were in rows but it is for work and I am not at liberty to change it in this way. Unfortunately it is for an existing excel sheet and I have been told that too many people use the sheet to change it. I am aware of the short comings in structuring it this way.

Comment: @bloopiebloopie: If "Start" and "End" *aren't* in rows, where are they?  I did nothing to suggest that the spreadsheet be changed; I was just trying to confirm what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I want to search one row for a value. I want to find the column at which that value is located.

Comment: Editing for grammar and clarifying question based on comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use any column, than here is the formula only approach.
Just place this formula in any column in which you want the result and drag it down.

```
=IF(MATCH("End",1:1,0)-MATCH("Start",1:1,0)>1,
MATCH("End",1:1,0)-MATCH("Start",1:1,0)-1&" cells between Start and End",
"Nothing between Start and End")
```

Here is the data that I've used and result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will process the first **10** rows.  Adjust to suit your needs:

```
Sub WhatsInBetween()
    Dim i As Long, st As String, en As String
    Dim M As Long, N As Long
    st = "start"
    en = "end"

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To 10
            N = .Match(st, Rows(i), 0)
            M = .Match(en, Rows(i), 0)
            If M = N + 1 Then
                MsgBox "for row " & i & " nothing between"
            Else
                MsgBox "for row " & i & " something between"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```